# How do I upload images to my heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am following a tutorial on deploying a Rails app to Heroku.  It is using a free heroku account with a name like tranquil-mountain-51138.herokuapp.com.  The tutorial does not cover adding images.  I have a simple test site up and working.  Now, I'd like to add a few images to the site, but have no idea how to do this.

On non-heroku, non-rails apps I use FileZilla to ftp files to the server, so I'm very familiar with that.  Is there something similar for heroku?

Would someone point me to a tutorial on how to do this?

Much appreciated.

EDITED
I would like to upload a photo to appear on my public/index.html page.  That's all.  I created and deployed a simple job-tracking app, which does not need pictures. Now I am just looking for a "how to" on adding images to an app on heroku - for learning purposes.

Thanks

Comment: Deploying on Heroku is usually the last step of a Rails application. Adding images, on the countrary is a feature among so many others on your app. Have you started coding controllers, models ? I guess your application is not only about showing images to users... please tell us more

Comment: edited my post.  Just need to know how to add one image to my small app.  I am not doing an app that allows users to upload images. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, Heroku doesn't allow writes on its filesystem, so, you would not be able to upload a file t your application at Heroku. That's why [they suggest](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) you to use and integrate Amazon S3 as a storage option.

Answer (score 2):

Since your comment says you aren't allowing users to upload images you don't need to do anything at all for displaying existing images (or files in general) to Heroku.  As long as you have the images in your assets/images folder and it is referenced and setup in your app on your local machine, it will be permanently stored by Heroku and displayed on your site when you "git push heroku master".  Just keep in mind, there is additional work to be done if you decide to have users upload pictures which involves adding Paperclip & S3 storage on Amazon since Heroku uses an ephermeal storage system.

**Summary**: Just deploy your app and your images will be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display an image that you provide, just add the appropriate helper in your view file :

```
image_tag('myimage')
```

myimage being located in `app/assets/images` folder. When an image is located in that specific folder, it will belong to the asset pipeline and then will be discovered automatically by the Rails app.

If you want to allow your users to upload images, then you have to use a gem such as Paperclip or Carrierwave which will allow to upload the image remotely (to Amazon S3 or other data services)

Comment: Thank you, I understand all of that.  What I want though, is to know how do I get an image from my computer up onto the heroku server so my code will see it?  Does the image get pushed up in my push command if it is in my git repo?  Sorry for not explaining this better.

Comment: Got it, finally.  Thanks for making me THINK!   I work in a world where we ftp images to a directory.  My mind was not thinking of using git to push the image up.  Sigh!

Answer (score 0):

You can not store in Heroku's filesystem as that use to change after some time but yes you can use s3 provided by aws or there is an app available into Heroku https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary can help you to store images.

Also if you want to upload the image into the background you can use Redis to do that as there is not fix filesystem for it you can follow the [link](https://arvindvyas07.blogspot.com/2020/05/photos-upload-in-background-with.html) for same